Using the result of a ForEach-Object in a file import for the file name
I have two PowerShell scripts one is Get-ChildItem (a file name from a given set of folders) and the second is Import-Csv of a CSV file that outputs a couple of fields from the CSV. How do I take the ForEach-Object {$_.Name} and put it into my Import-Csv?
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path '\\xyz' -Filter *.csv |
ForEach-Object {$_.Name}

$fileimport =Import-Csv \\xyz\$_.name -Delimiter ","


$fileimpot.Item 


Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path '\xyz' -Filter *.csv | Import-Csv, no assignment needed

So how does the $.name get assigned to: $fileimport =Import-Csv \xyz$.name -Delimiter ","?

$_ is assigned by ForEach-Object: Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path '\\xyz' -Filter *.csv | ForEach-Object { Write-Host "Importing $($_.Name)"; Import-Csv $_.FullName}

in my example, i was only displaying the $fileimport.Item, however, I am seeing all columns in the csv How do I get only the Fileimport.item not all columns

You mean you want only the specific column value per row? $fileimport |ForEach-Object { <# now you can work with 1 $_.Item at a time #>}

How do i mark your answer as the solution?
